# What is "вот тебе раз" and how do you use it?

Tags: значения

so I'm learning a few phrases in Russian and I came across this sentence, but I'm not sure of what it means, like the few online translators that I have tried tell me that is something like "Here you have it" or "Here's one for you", but as much as I try to understand the few examples that I've seen I just don't seem to get it. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Note that there are two forms of this saying. Literary - "Вот тебе и раз" and colloquial - "Вот те раз". A mix of those forms ("Вот тебе раз") is only rarely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Вот тебе и раз" they say when something rather unpleasant happens, but at the same time you remain calm

-Я сегодня поцарапал телефон

-Вот тебе и раз...

In english - something like that:

-I scratched my phone today

-Oh no (calmly, without emotion)

More examples of phrases to which you can respond "вот тебе и раз":

- холодильник сломался
- я не хочу идти с тобой в парк
- погода испортилась
- автобус поедет по другому маршруту

Comment: Thank you very much!